# Installing JavaMail and JAF and setting the classpath to send emails using Java

Tags: java, email, frameworks, classpath, jakarta-mail

I'm planning to develop an application based on Java in order to send emails. I read in a blog about it. Based on the blog, i was told to install JavaMail API and Java Activation Framework. Can anyone help me regarding this installment and setting the classpath by adding mail.jar and activation.jar files.

Comment: which IDE you are using ?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE

Comment: Start with a maven project and only you have to add the dependencies in your pom file. Have you any idea about maven ?  Here is the dependency of java mail api.

 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Sorry, i don't have any idea about maven

Comment: ok , see tutorial  "How to create maven based project in Net beans". these are very simple steps to create a Maven project. It automatically creates a pom.xml 
 file in your project. then you add the dependecy (which iwas provided in above comment) in <dependencies> Tag in your pom.xml. your project automatically download the all dependencies. then you are good to Go. start Writing the code.